# Distributing the maven settings.xml file in corporate environment

Tags: java, maven-2

We want to deploy maven in our company, and we are wondering what's the best way to distribute the file settings.xml and maybe associated data to each developer.  We see these constraints:

- We want a '**batteries included**' strategy': The minimal amount of work to set up a correct environment.
- We have **roaming profiles**, so we can't store the full maven repository cache in the profile (need for creating a folder for this cache outside the profile)
- We want to push little updates to this file without destroying **local modifications** (so no overwrite, but e.g. a subversion merge would be usable)
- We want to use developer-style tools only, so we **don't depend on the windows guys** with all associated overhead of a release to push a little change  (using GPOs or SMS to push this file is not preferred)

So how does your company handle this?

Comment: Hi hyperman I have a similar requirement for pushing the settings.xml changes to developers local environment. Any suggestion how you implemented it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `settings.xml` in a version control system, we use Git, we tell the repository to ignore the `repository` directory in `~/.m2` in a `.gitignore` file and then just pull the `settings.xml` file on a regular basis from a central remote repository, in our case a private Gitorious` server.

Once this file is set up and working once, it is rare that it should ever change in most cases. So just putting the `settings.xml` file on a wiki and having the user install it when they are installing the version control software and Maven isn't much of an extra burden.

Comment: Just found out an extra requirement: We would like to use the single sign on password to deploy artefacts, and it is stored in the settings.xml.  So it seems we will update the file on a regular base, just to update this password.

Also,

*Batteries included: There seem to be quite a lot of these 'one off' files in our dev environment, so i try to avoid putting it on a wike (requiring manual action at update)

*Merging local modifications is hard in this strategy